# Error module Qt

Tags: qt, webkit, qwebview

I'm new to QT. I have a problem with a widget named QWebView as when I want to compile it says : unknown module in QT: webkit
I wrote in my qmake.pro file the line : 
    QT       += core gui network webkit

Am I wrong ? I read in doc I just need to add this package.
I'm on QT 5.8 on macbook.

If anyone could help, I'll be thankful !

Answer (score 0):

Qt 5.8 doesn't include the webkit module. Use the webengine or webview module instead.

Since you're on a mac, if you're OK with Qt 5.7 included in macports, you'll get webkit module there as well:

```
sudo port install qt5-qtwebkit
```